# C# Sending a Server QUERY to CMD and Reading the Output

Tags: c#, cmd, output, citrix

UPDATE - My code now looks like this, and the file test.txt is generated after running, but the file is empty, so I'm assuming the command is not being sent to the CMD properly:

```
    static void command()
    {
        string cmd = "/c QUERY session >C:/test.txt";

        Process proc = new Process();

        proc.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;

        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd;

        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();    
    }
```

Can anyone think of a way for me to debug this?
Visual Studio shows no errors so it is hard to tell what is going on.

Any help is much appreciated!

---

After having a look around on StackExchange, I have ended up with the following code for opening the command prompt and sending a command:

```
        string cmd = "/c QUERY user /SERVER: servername.goes.here";
        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.Start();

        string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        MessageBox.Show(output);

        proc.WaitForExit();
```

When replacing the Server Query with a simple "`notepad.exe`", CMD window opens when running, and so does `notepad.exe`.

However, when sending the Server query (This is to check which users are using a particular Citrix server), I am seeing this message in the CMD:

> 'QUERY' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

When I manually type the query into CMD, I am presented with a list of all users currently logged in to that particular server.

What I would like for the program to run the SERVER query, and send the output to a message window, so that I know it has worked.

Any help with this is much appreciated!

Many thanks

I also noticed that when removing the `/c` from the cmd String, I don't see a query error in the CMD, but seeing no output either here or in the message box

Comment: did you try it as "cmd /c QUERY user /SERVER: servername.goes.here";

Comment: Hi Muhammad, thanks for the reply. I have just tried that but there is no change from the previous version ("/c QUERY..etc...")

Comment: Hi. Why don't you use Citrix XenApp SDK to get this info?

Comment: Hi Mikhail - We need this tool to be accessible by users of our Xenapp thin clients, and I don't think they have powershell enabled, but I may be wrong - perhaps I will look into this, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '/c' part of the argument simply means run the follow code. Without that it will not execute the code you are feeding it.  The error message you see means that the QUERY program cannot be found by the current environment. For the command line to "see" the program it has to either be a part of the OS PATH environment variable OR it has to be in the current working directory. You can change the current working directory to the directory that contains the QUERY.exe program by executing the CD command (Change Directory).

You can pipe individual commands into the same /c switch by using a '&' in between the individual statements.

```
cmd.exe /c CD "PATH TO TOOLS FOLDER" & QUERY user /SERVER: servername.goes.here
```

Another way would be to provide the full path to the QUERY.exe program.

```
cmd.exe /c "C:\Program Files\Example\Tools\bin\QUERY.exe" user /SERVER: servername.goes.here
```

[Read more about the cmd line switches](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your reply. What is strange about this, is that I seem to be able to run my QUERY from anywhere else, as long as I am entering it manually into CMD. I can even create a batch file which runs the query successfully, but the trouble is that I have no idea how to get the output.

Comment: You couldn't redirect the output into a file using a greater than symbol(>)?

Comment: Hi JB - Just found this method and testing it now.

Comment: If you are not providing in the absolute full path to the program "C:\Program Files\Example\Tools\Bin\QUERY.exe" the program has to have a way to "FIND" it. It does this by first looking in the current directory or by looking up the system environment variables PATH. The program you are executing can have a completed different set of environment variables and it can start in a different folder then if you are typing in the commands by hand.

Comment: Also look into using the ProcessStartInfo.LoadUserProfile property and setting that to TRUE. That may be the fix you are looking for as it will load the environment variables for your current user.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Andrew, I have updated my code to set LoadUserProfile to True, but this doesn't seem to have had an effect. The current code is creating the test.txt file in the correct location but it is blank, meaning that the console must be running, but not returning anything. When I type the same line into CMD manually, the correct result is returned